# How to use UITextView in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I created a popup alert using alert controller and added two alert actions(ok and cancel) as below.

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Cycling"
                              message:@"Please enter title and description"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];

[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, i want add UITextView. Because I have two text field like title and description. For description i want to use UITextView for adding no.of lines. I tried i am not getting how to add it.

Please advice.

Comment: Don't, use a custom view, or view controller presented modally.

Comment: @vikingosegundo alright... apologies. and thanks

Answer (score 11):

Johno2110's solution worked best for me with a little cleanup and tweaking. Posting the code and a screenshot of the result here in case it helps anybody else out.

Confirmed working with Swift 5.

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)

@IBAction func sendFeedback(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Feedback \n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action) in
        alertController.view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { (action) in
        let enteredText = self.textView.text
        alertController.view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    }
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)

    alertController.view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 5, bottom: 8, right: 5)
    alertController.view.addSubview(self.textView)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "bounds"{
        if let rect = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let margin: CGFloat = 8
            let xPos = rect.origin.x + margin
            let yPos = rect.origin.y + 54
            let width = rect.width - 2 * margin
            let height: CGFloat = 90

            textView.frame = CGRect.init(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: alert]

Comment: The buttons are getting hidden behind the keyboard on smaller devices. Any way to move the alert a little above the screen or may be reduce the size of textview

Answer (score 8):

Adding UITextView to UIAlertController:

https://gist.github.com/bennagar/c0cd618bcd23c4c2dadf

```
func showAlert() {

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    saveAction.enabled = false

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification, object: textView, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (notification) in
        saveAction.enabled = self.textView.text != ""
    }

    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    alertController.view.addSubview(self.textView)

    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "bounds"{
        if let rect = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue(){
            let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
            textView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + margin, rect.origin.y + margin, CGRectGetWidth(rect) - 2*margin, CGRectGetHeight(rect) / 2)
            textView.bounds = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + margin, rect.origin.y + margin, CGRectGetWidth(rect) - 2*margin, CGRectGetHeight(rect) / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/bennagar/c0cd618bcd23c4c2dadf.js"></script>
```

Still locking for way to get the height of the marked view, when I have it I can just replace the /2 with the correct height.
[image]

Comment: In Swift3, its throwing error even after modifying other variables: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.

Answer (score 7):

With the above solutions my textview was not positioned correctly. This is how I got it to work:

```
   // The \n is required so that the alertcontroller keeps space for the message. Add as many \n as you like your textview height to be
   self.alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                                              message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   self.alertController.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
   UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   textView.editable = NO;
   textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
   textView.text = @"Some really long text here";
   textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   // This will make the scroll view scrollable if the text is too long
   textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
   NSLayoutConstraint *leadConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.alertController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:-8.0];
       NSLayoutConstraint *trailConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.alertController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:8.0];

   NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.alertController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:-64.0];
   NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.alertController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:64.0];
   [self.retailerHelpAlertController.view addSubview:textView];
   [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[leadConstraint, trailConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
```

Comment: Great Thanks aloooot! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
 let textView = UITextView()
 textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

 let controller = UIViewController()

 textView.frame = controller.view.frame
 controller.view.addSubview(textView)

 alert.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")

 let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.height * 0.8)
 alert.view.addConstraint(height)

 present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

Fantastic solutions above. Some needed some manipulation to work for Swift 4.2, here is the conversion for that. I've also added some padding in the TextView to make it athletically more pleasing.

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)

@IBAction func alert(_ sender: Any) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 5, bottom: 8, right: 5)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.label.text = self.textView.text
        alertController.view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    }

    saveAction.isEnabled = false

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action) in
        alertController.view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    }

    alertController.view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: textView, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
        saveAction.isEnabled = self.textView.text != ""
    }

    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    alertController.view.addSubview(self.textView)

    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "bounds"{
        if let rect = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
            textView.frame = CGRect.init(x: rect.origin.x + margin, y: rect.origin.y + margin, width: rect.width - 2*margin, height: rect.height / 2)
            textView.bounds = CGRect.init(x: rect.origin.x + margin, y: rect.origin.y + margin, width: rect.width - 2*margin, height: rect.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very well and looks great. You can use the message field of the alert field to direct the user to input something (since the title field is hidden by the textview).

Comment: This is not working as expected , here i am not getting textview inside the popup , It comes with title and buttons only

Comment: The popup is centered on screen and the keyboard overlaps buttons, and no way to dismiss it !

Answer (score -1):

```
    // Create a custom UIViewController to be used as the content view controller
    let customViewController = UIViewController()
    
    let aletController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Note", message: "Hello", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create the UITextView
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 250, height: 100))
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textView.backgroundColor = .white
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    textView.textAlignment = .left
    textView.isEditable = true
    
    // Add the UITextView as a subview of the custom view controller
    customViewController.view.addSubview(textView)
    
    // Set the custom view controller as the content view controller of the UIAlertController
    alertController.setValue(customViewController, forKey: "contentViewController")
    
    // Add a "Save" action to the UIAlertController
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { _ in
      
    }
    saveAction.isEnabled = false
    
    // Add a "Cancel" action to the UIAlertController
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: textView, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
        saveAction.isEnabled = textView.text != ""
    }
    
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    // Present the UIAlertController
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code I got from here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title", message:@"Message", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"LoginPlaceholder", @"Login"); 
}];
```

Then show it.

Comment: How do i add multiple lines.

Comment: I would either add more than one UITextView OR make my own UIView subclass with a UITextView in it.

Comment: more than one UITextView.

Comment: I would assume that you just repeat the [alertController addTextFieldWith...] line and the two below (unless you don't want to customise it) and the new text view will be added below the first.

Comment: i think he want a UITextVIEW which is different from a UITextFIELD... a FIELD is one line of editing, for a title, and a VIEW has multiple lines, for a description