# Constraints to UITextView inside UIAlertViewConroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uialertviewcontroller

I have a `UITextView` inside `UIAlertViewController`. I need to set leading and trailing constraints to `UITextView` programatically.

Screenshot

[image]

Here is my code

```
func popUpController()
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Additional Notes", message: "Write your additional notes here.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    let color = UIColor(red: 224/255, green: 224/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    textView.layer.borderColor = color
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    let controller = MyActivitiesViewController()

    textView.frame = controller.view.frame
    controller.view.addSubview(textView)

    alert.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")

    let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 180)
    alert.view.addConstraint(height)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {

        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    })

}
```

Comment: According to Apple docs: `**Important** The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.` You are much better off presenting your own controller instead of trying to do something you're explicitly *not* supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this only a work around.

If you want to give more height to the alertcontroller add more ***new line*** to ***title***.

Adjust the ***constraints*** according to your requirement if you wish to modify this

```
 func showAlertController()
    {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your title \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let customView = UITextView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        alertController.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
        let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Some Action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

            print(customView.text)

        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})

        alertController.addAction(somethingAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


        alertController.view.addSubview(customView)

        customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

        customView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        customView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.present(alertController, animated: true) {

        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Updated answer please check

Comment: @Anurai tried, how can I decrease height of customView

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae. Either you can reduce the no of newline in title or you should adjust the top or bottom anchor offset values .